# Insert Time and Date into Database using mysql_query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, database

```
 <form action="actionMAppointment.php?stu_id=<?php echo $row_RecEdit['stu_id'] ?>" method="post">
        Time:
        <input type = "time" name="appointmentTime" id = "appointmentTime" />
        Date:
        <input type = "text" name="appointmentDate" id = "appointmentDate" />
        <input type = "submit" value="Make Appointment"/>
 </form>
```

actionMAppointment.php

```
$temp_id = $_GET['stu_id'];
$app_time    = $_POST['appointmentTime'];
$app_date    = $_POST['appointmentDate'];
$the_time = date('h:i A', strtotime($app_time));
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_studentdetail SET stu_appointment = 1, appointment_time = $the_time, appointment_date = $app_date WHERE stu_id = $temp_id"); 
header("Location:appointment.php");
?>
```

Javascript for date

```
<style type="text/css">@import "js_pickdate/jquery.datepick.css";</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_pickdate/jquery.datepick.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#appointmentDate').datepick({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

For some reason it doesnt update the database at all. Can anyone help out Thanks!

Comment: maybe because your installation doesn't support mysql_* functions

Comment: [check how to debug php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) and also be sure to stop using mysql_ immediately.  if you use [parametized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) you will not only get your insert working, but you will also avoid nasty sql injection.

Comment: what are the type of appointment_time and appointment_date in mysql table?

Comment: Check your current version of php.. If its above 5.* you need to change your code. As this code is deprecated now. Try changing it with advance php.

Comment: Read up on using prepared statements with mysqli_* functions, or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should change

```
$('#appointmentDate').datepick({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

to

```
 $('#appointmentDate').datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
```